# Is there a possible way to make this button animate?

Tags: html, css

I am recently trying to code an animated button (It's a decorated link to be specific) using HTML/CSS, disputing all the things I need to avoid, I have one problem left to succeed: Make the following-coded button animate like the transform property on hover and active.

```css
.button{
  display:inline;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:50px;
  font-family:monospace;
  color:blue;
  margin:15px;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background-color:lightgreen;
  box-shadow:5px 10px grey;
  border-radius:15px;
  position:relative;
}
.button:hover{
  background-color:yellow;
  color:darkgreen;
  top:-5px;
  left:-3px;
  box-shadow:8px 15px grey;
}
.button:active{
  top:+3px;
  left:+5px;
  box-shadow:5px 5px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Button</div>
```

Comment: you need to (1) set default values (2) add transtiion and there is no `+3px`, it's invalid

Comment: @TemaniAfif — `+3px` isn't invalid, it's just very non-idiomatic.

Comment: @Cyh1368 Do you just want to animate the hover and focus effects (instead of having them be instant)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use `transition` to set which properties should be animated (i.e. `all`), how long the animation should last (I've usually go for `0.25s` for hover effects) and the timing function.

You also need to define all of the properties you are using in `:hover` in the default block as well (i.e. `top`, `left`)

```css
.button {
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: blue;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px grey;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: darkgreen;
  top: -5px;
  left: -3px;
  box-shadow: 8px 15px grey;
}

.button:active {
  top: 3px;
  left: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px grey;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Hello</button>
```

Comment: Did I miss something? Why the downvotes?

Comment: IT WORKED! As the publisher, I think there are no mistakes!

Comment: @Cyh1368 If my answer solved your problem, you can accept and/or upvote it.